# WPF: Multiple UI's triggering one command

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, plot

**Scenario**

You perform an analysis and you would like to plot the results. Your analysis results are shown on different UI components, and you also have some other UI components that let you customize your plot. In this regard, lets suppose:

- You have `Datagrid_1` that shows analysis results
- A `Combobox` that lets you choose the resolution of plot
- some `Radiobuttons` which let you choose the type of plot (i.e., bar plot, heatmap, and etc.,)
- And finally, you have a small datagrid (`Datagrid_2`) that you can choose different regression models.

In simple, You can have a `Button` that it's `Command` is bound to a function that will update the plot based on your selections on UI elements. That is achieved by letting you choose your preferences and then click on `Button`. However, to improve user experience, we would like to make the process automatic. That means the moment any of your selections is changed, the plot updates automatically. That means: we totally remove `Button`.

```
If `DataGrid_1` `selectedItem` is changed
If `Combobox` `selectedIndex` is changed
If a `RadioButton` is `Checked`
If `DataGrid_2` `selectedItem` is changed
     I would like the plot to be refreshed.
```

**Question**

Given that my application is implemented in `MVVM` pattern, what would be the best work around for my scenario ?

Comment: Which of the said UI elements takes part on choosing the result? From your text, I would say DataGrid1 is the filtered one,, right?

Comment: yes, `datagrid_1` chooses the results.

Answer (score 1):

1) Make a property for evert filter that might be selected. Those do not need to notify change.

2) Bind that property to the selectedItem of both grid and combo.

3) Make a bool property for each radio and bind it to the IsChecked property for the radios.

4) Bind the old Refresh command to SelectedItem changed of both grid and combo, and to the Checked and Unchecked of every radio. You'll have to use interaction triggers to do that.

5) Make the itemsSource of the target grid notify changes.

6) Change the refresh command as to use those filter properties and set the result to the itemsSource property.

I'll post some code sample tomorrow if nobody answers and time allows it!

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using the MVVM pattern, an easy way to do this would be for the databound properties to trigger a data refresh for Datagrid_1 when they change.

e.g.

```
private Object _selectedComboBoxProperty;
public Object SelectedComboBoxProperty 
{
   get { return _selectedComboBoxProperty; }
   set { 
       _selectedComboBoxProperty = value;

       // Notify property changed
       OnPropertyChanged("SelectedComboBoxProperty");

       // Update Datagrid_1
       UpdateResults();
}

private void UpdateResults()
{
   // Inspect the current values of your selection properties

   // Some business logic to filter the results


   // Refresh the collection bound to the Datagrid_1

}
```